# AutoLevel(Channels.RGB) seems to have no effect

Tags: magick.net

I'm trying to autolevel an image. My code looks like this:

```cs
MagickImage image = new MagickImage(stream);
image.AutoLevel(Channels.RGB);
```

Later in the code I'm sending the image to a web response.
For some reason, this code has no effect on the image. It looks exactly the same as the original. If I change to:

```cs
MagickImage image = new MagickImage(stream);
image.Posterize(2);
```

Then I clearly see the filter applied.

What am I missing with AutoLevel?

**Update:**

I tried this code:

```cs
var image1 = Image.Clone();
Image.AutoLevel(Channels.RGB);
var diff = Image.Compare(image1, ErrorMetric.RootMeanSquared);
```

and the value of diff is 0.0, while with this code (and using the same image):

```cs
var image1 = Image.Clone();
Image.Equalize();
var diff = Image.Compare(image1, ErrorMetric.RootMeanSquared);
```

the value of diff is 0.315

Comment: Just to clarify, the value of diff is 0.0 no matter which photo I use

Answer (score 0):

The effect of `AutoLevel` might not be noticeable depending on your input image. I did a quick test with the following code:

```cs
using (MagickImage imageA = new MagickImage("logo:"))
{
  imageA.Write(@"c:\imageA.jpg")

  imageA.AutoLevel(Channels.Default);

  using (MagickImage imageB = new MagickImage("logo:"))
  {
    double difference = imageA.Compare(imageB, ErrorMetric.RootMeanSquared);
    Assert.AreNotEqual(0.0, difference);

    imageB.Write(@"c:\imageB.jpg")
  }
}
```

This tests passed but the value of difference is very small. This means that when you compare the images with your eyes you will probably not be able to find a big difference.

And below is an example that will show you that the `AutoLevel` method does something when you use another input image.

```cs
using (MagickImage imageA = new MagickImage("gradient:gray70-gray30", 150, 100))
{
  imageA.Write(@"c:\imageA.jpg")

  imageA.AutoLevel(Channels.Default);

  using (MagickImage imageB = new MagickImage("gradient:gray70-gray30", 150, 100))
  {
    double difference = imageA.Compare(imageB, ErrorMetric.RootMeanSquared);
    Assert.AreNotEqual(0.0, difference);

    imageB.Write(@"c:\imageB.jpg")
  }
}
```